# How Can I Create a Custom File Upload With Only HTML, JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the design of the control I want to create:

[image: sample design]

As you can see, it's easy to create the design except the browse button of upload control. I created the rest. I've been searching about changing the place of Browse button but could not find anything useful.

So, how to do that? There was an idea like embedding an unvisible upload control over button but any other advice is golden, thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's actually not as complicated as you may think. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/sSSNj/). Stylize your button how you will!

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadme" />
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Upload Stuff!" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=file] { 
    width: 1px; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        $('#uploadme').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. I forked your fiddle. This will display the file name in a textbox next to the button when the file has been selected.  http://jsfiddle.net/nKVkM/

Comment: On the surface this seems to work very well, but when I try it on a real form and try to submit the form, IE8 doesn't submit the form the first time I click the submit button.  Instead it just clears the file upload control (I had to make it visible to confirm this part), then if I click submit again it works.  I'm guessing this is a security feature, trying to avoid people making it not-obvious what you are uploading.

Comment: More about why this doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8

Comment: @eselk yes, if you are trying to submit the form using a basic form POST it will not work. however, given that javascript penetration is over 99%, you can programmatically submit your form and not really worry about the three people in the world who have JS turned off.

Answer (score 6):

Here's are two excellent articles which shows you how to customize the appearance of file inputs.

**[jQuery Custom File Upload Input: from the book Designing with Progressive Enhancement](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-custom-file-input-book-designing-with-progressive-enhancement)** by the Filament Group

**[Styling File Inputs with CSS and the DOM](https://web.archive.org/web/20230531053911/http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom)** by Shaun Inman

Comment: Links not working

Comment: @Sushan I updated the links.

Answer (score 5):

For a solution that does not require JavaScript, you could use a `<label>`:

```
<label for="upload">Upload</label>
<input type="file" id="upload" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden"/>
```

This won't work in every browser, namely older ones and mobile Safari. To cover these, use the above mentioned JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 4):

another example:

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/cXVRe/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-green"><input class="file-upload" type="file">Upload File</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button-green
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe","Verdana";
    background: #0f9e0a center top no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(15, 158, 10), rgb(24, 105, 21)); 
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 82px;  
    position: relative; 
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
}

.button-green:hover
{
    background: #0a8406 center top no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(12, 141, 8), rgb(19, 88, 17));     
}

.file-upload
{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 102px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```