# Custom file upload with JS, HTML and CSS in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a file upload form, but the < input type="file" > tag is too ugly and not customizable, that's why I did a trick. The base idea came from here:

[How Can I Create a Custom File Upload With Only HTML, JS and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794039/how-can-i-create-a-custom-file-upload-with-only-html-js-and-css)

The problem is when I specify the name property in this tag the upload will not work in IE. check it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3a3J/35/

use the Browse and Upload buttons. In the first case it will work, the data is sent and the page is refreshed. But in the second case if you click the Upload button it will just erase the path from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly because `IE8` does not support `CSS3`

Comment: Where are you seeing here CSS3? :)

Comment: @sunmao:  for example you are using `-moz-border-bottom-colors` which is a CSS3 http://www.css3.info/preview/colored-border/

Comment: Yes you are right! And do you think is it relevant? Then just delete the CSS part, you will get the same issue.

Comment: -moz-border-bottom-colors is neither CSS3 nor standard, and no CSS code would ever cause anything even remotely similar to sunmao's issue.