# jQuery input file click method and access denied on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, access-denied, input-type-file

I'm trying to use only a button as input file, it works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari but not in IE... I always get 'access denied' when submitting the form.

The code:

```
$('#input_file').click();
```

Is there a real fix for it? I wasted about 2 hours on google but I can't find it.

Comment: $("#input_file").change() will not open browser dialog

Comment: How about [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or similar?

Comment: Do u have a live version of the form?

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SJWcw/.

Comment: @pimvdb, i mean when i submit the form....

Comment: @pimvdb, it works fine in ie but when i try to submit the form i get 'access denied'

Comment: @Sonia: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/SJWcw/2/ Submitting after selecting with the special button works.

Comment: @pimvdb, ye test it on ie and u'll get it.

Comment: @pimvdb, u should set enctype as multipart/form-data and method as post then submit it and u'll get the error access denied, try it on ie.

Comment: @SoniaL Then perhaps this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around it.
Wrap the button in label tags like this:

```
<label for="fileinput"><div class="button">Upload file</div></label>


<form>
  <input id="fileinput" name="file" type="file">
</form>
```

Clicking the label will trigger the file input without invalidating the form in internet explorer 
(tested in IE9 & IE10)

EDIT: serve this code to IE and keep the javascript solution for other browsers. Firefox will not trigger the file input field when the label is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I once saw this piece of code, I don't remember where but it is a workaround

```
  if ($.browser.msie) {
        // IE suspends timeouts until after the file dialog closes
        $flUpload.click(function (event) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                changeFunc();
            }, 0);
        });
    }
    else {
        // All other browsers behave
        $flUpload.change(changeFunc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Security sandbox "feature" of IE. There is no way to get around it. Sorry. I use the JQuery file input, but still have to detect IE and use the IE basic input, I have spend a lot of time looking for answers and haven't found any. You could use flash, which is what [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) does to get around the security of IE. I recommend it, it's a pretty damn good plug-in.