# How to apply stylesheet to input type=file for IE8 or how to make textfield of input type=file single clickable in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, input-type-file

I am developing a website for IE8 (client requirement) in which I am providing a image upload functionality. Using CSS I made browse button (i.e. input type=file) as image (image on back and setting opacity of browse button to 0).

So whenever user clicks on image I want to open file uploader popup. I have attached two images. One with opacity 0 and one without opacity.

IN IE8 input type file comes with one text box in left side and one browse button on right side. To open uploader popup I can single click on browse button but I need to double click on text box which my client dont want.

For a work around I added one new button on top of input type=file and on its onclick event I triggered click event of browse button. It opens file uploader but when I post form image does not get uploaded and failed with error code 4 (which is no file uploaded).

Is there any way so that I can make this as single click only in IE8. In all other browsers its working perfectly with single click only.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

[image: browse button will appear on html]

[image: browse button actually presented]

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8 .
In short the answer is that it might not be possible to do so in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MtHPr/6/) fiddle.

Clicks that don't originate from the user won't function properly. Styling the file input field doesn't change the size of the button beyond a limit, so what you can do is use the zoom property.

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but using the following CSS for the parent and the file input works, so you can tweak the values to fit your needs:

```
.uploadTrigger {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTB47.png") center -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.uploadTrigger input[type="file"] {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    zoom: 10;
    -moz-transform: scale(10) translate(22px, 22px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

If you try changing the opacity to 1, you'll notice that the button takes up the entire parent, thus allowing your user to use a single click to open the file selection window.

The code above has been modified to provide consistent behavior in IE9, Chrome(28) and Firefox(21). If you're developing an internal site and you're sure only IE8 support is required, you can strip out the `-moz-transform: scale(10) translate(22px, 22px);`

I'll test it on IE8 later and update if it's found to be dysfunctional.