# submit form with input file IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, submit, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting access is denied error on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8)

i found some [**questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input) about trigger a `<input type='file' />` to submit a form. All of this because i need a custom input file.

making some tests with this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/234/), i found that the trigger to submit the form works if i **dont** put a `name` in the input file, this issue only happens in **IE**.

So, how can i submit a image with no name using a `form`, is this possible using jquery?

i think the solution was just to browsers !IE

Is there any other way to submit?

**js:**

```
$(".some-button").click(function() {
   $("#test").click();
})

$('#test').change(function() {
   $('#test_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: what name where you giving the imput?

Comment: `<input type="file" id="test" name="test_name">` anyone.. all return a error in script `SCRIPT5: Access Deny`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/241/

I was able to get it to work in IE9 by setting a delay, via `setTimeout`.  I did not test this on other browsers, but as you have it working in other browsers then if the `setTimeout` doesn't help in those browsers you can always do browser sniffing (which jquery has, of course) to do the appropriate submission method.