# Custom client side validation with uploading a file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I'm creating my own data annotation with client side validation to check if the chosen files are allowed, but i can't get it to work. The client side method doesn't get fired up.

I'm not getting any JavaScript errors.

Model:

```
public class FotoAlbumModel
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }

    [Filters.Required]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Dit veld mag niet langer zijn dan 150 tekens.")]
    public string Titel { get; set; }

     [Filters.Required]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Dit veld mag niet langer zijn dan 2500 tekens.")]
    public string Descriptie { get; set; }

    [Filters.Required]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Dit veld mag niet langer zijn dan 250 tekens.")]
    public string Keywoorden { get; set; }

    [Filters.Required]
    [LinkName]
    public string Linknaam { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int AantalFotos { get; set; }

  [Filters.FileExtensions(FileExtensions = ".bmp,.jpg,.png.gif,.jpeg")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] Fotos { get; set; }
}
```

My annotation:

```
public class FileExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string FileExtensions { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = value == null ? "" : value.ToString();

        string[] arrayFileExtensions = FileExtensions.Split(',');

        bool isMatch = arrayFileExtensions.Any(x => x.Contains(Path.GetExtension(strValue)));

        if (!isMatch && ErrorMessage == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "De extensie van de bestand is niet toegestaan.";
        }
        return isMatch;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = "De extensie van de bestand is niet toegestaan.",
            ValidationType = "fileextension"

        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("allowedextensions", FileExtensions);

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

My custom validation adapter:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("fileextension", "allowedextensions");

$.validator.addMethod("fileextension", function (value, element, allowedextensions) {
alert('sds');
var arrayAllowedExtensions = allowedextensions.split(',');
var fileExtension = value.split('.').pop();
$.each(arrayAllowedExtensions, function(extension) {
    if (extension == fileExtension) {
        return true;
    }
});
return false;
});
```

Html:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Fotos, new {@type="file", @multiple="true", @onchange="makeFileList();", @id="filesToUpload", @style="display: none;"})
                                <input type="button" value="Plaatje(s) selecteren" class="btn btn-green btn-gradient" onclick="document.getElementById('filesToUpload').click();" />
                            <ul id="fileList">
                                <li>No Files Selected</li>
                            </ul>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Fotos)
```

MakeFileList Javascript function:

```
<script>
    function makeFileList() {
        var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
        var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
        while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
            ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = input.files[i].name;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        if(!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = 'No Files Selected';
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas why the method is not being fired up?

Comment: Can you show the makeFileList() js function, and the model property with the data annotation please?

Comment: I can't see the makeFileList() function

Comment: You've written: ".bmp,.jpg,.png.gif,.jpeg" instead of: ".bmp,.jpg,.png,.gif,.jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you're hiding the control that the FileExtensionsAttribute code is trying to validate.

Look at your page using Firebug, and you can see that the hidden control `<input id="filesToUpload" type="file"` has the validation `data-val-fileextension="De extensie van de bestand is niet toegestaan."`

If you modify your textbox `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Fotos` by removing the `@style="display: none;"` attribute, you'll see that your validation works.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get round this problem. Is there a reason you can't use the standard file upload control?

Comment: Have you tried styling the standard file upload button? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401550/adding-style-to-file-upload-button-in-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401550/adding-style-to-file-upload-button-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

change the: `@onchange="makeFileList();"` on `@Html.TextBoxFor(,,`
to: `@onchange="makeFileList()"` (remove the semi-colon at the end)