# Add class to button of FileField form in Django

Tags: jquery, css, django, django-forms

I want to change the *css* of a button of *FileField* form adding a class of *Materializecss*:

[image]

I tried using jQuery with this code:

```
$(":input").addClass("btn");
```

But it doesnt add the style to the button, it does for the whole input (logic):

[image]

So how can I access to the button? Is there any way to add the `class="btn"` to the button of the Filefield of the form model of Django?

Form code:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label="Select a file")
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929363/how-can-you-style-djangos-file-picker-form-button

Comment: @select id of input element rather than all the inputs of the page.

Comment: Your jQuery code is not selecting the button it's selecting the input.

Comment: @macksol theres no button in the code, thats the problem. If I select button, nothing is selected