# jquery.form.js image uploading isn't working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm using jquery.form.js to upload images and it's working in all browsers, except IE.
version: 3.32.0-2013.04.03

I'm getting SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
jquery.form.js, line 531 character 21

I'm also using a custom upload button to submit the file which may be a part of the problem, but I'm not sure.

I even tried changing to another plugin without success, but I'd really like to get this one to work as I'm using the plugin in other pages of the site.

HTML: 
    `<input type="button" id="uploadButton" name="upload" value="" class="uploadButton"/>
              <br><div id="uploadLimit">Images cannot exceed 5mb.</div>
              <form id="uploadForm" action="inc/ajax-ftlib.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position:absolute;left:-99999px;">
                <input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="uploadImage">
                <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="0">
              </form>`

JS:

```
// hook up custom upload button
  $('#uploadButton').bind('click', function() {
    $('#uploadFile').trigger('click');
  });
  $('#uploadFile').bind('change', function() {
    $('#submit-btn').trigger('click');
  });

var options = {iframe: true, dataType: 'json', beforeSubmit: imageUploadRequest, success: imageUploadResponse, uploadProgress: imageUploadProgress, submit: imageUploadSubmit};
  $form = $('#uploadForm');
  $form.ajaxForm(options);

function imageUploadResponse(response){
  var fileName = response;
  //alert(fileName);
  // add the image to the thumbnail ui here / remove any loader image
  var path = "img/post/" + postId + "/" + fileName;
  var $newdiv = $('<div class="item" name=' + fileName + '><input type="button" class="thumbClose"/></div>');
  $newdiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');
  $("#list").append($newdiv);

  $('#uploadButton').show();
  $('#uploadLimit').show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IE does not allow you to upload a file if the file input it was selected with was tampered with JavaScript. Triggering that click event taints your file input so if you try to upload the file you get access denied. See also [getting access is denied error on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935001/getting-access-is-denied-error-on-ie8/4335390#4335390)